# SSAS Max calculation in cube

Tags: ssas, max, cube

I have a dimension list of Product Codes and a measure called ACV in my cube. I need to be able to calculate the maximum ACV value for each product code.

I have got as far as the calculation below but that returns the sum of ACV for all products.

MAX([Products].[Product Code].[Product Code].Members, [Measures].[ACV])

I'd be grateful for input on how to resolve my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the maximum evaluated semiadditively by the grain of your model designed in the data source view, you should add a new measure (based on the same source field as the ACV measure) to your cube add set its `AggregationFunction` property to `Max`. [More on aggregation functions in SSAS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175623.aspx#AggFunction).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. Thats absolutely perfect!